# Can't store array with mysqli [Error 1064]

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm trying to store a JSON-encoded array into MySql, but I get an error 1064.

My table structure:

[image]

And my code:

```
public static function addFriends($player, $friends = []){
    $array = json_encode($friends);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO friends (friends) VALUES ('$array') WHERE name = '" . $player . "'";
    $query = DatabaseManager::getConnection()->query($sql);
    if(!$query){
        echo mysqli_errno(DatabaseManager::getConnection());
        return;
    }
    echo 'Done';
}
```

The `$friends` array is like `["Car", "Plane", "Bug"]`.

Comment: You want to insert only one record with the field `friends` having the array values in form of the string `Car, Plane, Bug`? Or you want to insert a record for each array item?

Comment: Can you provide the **full** error message?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @NicoHaase How to get it? mysqli_errno display only 1064, nothing else

Comment: Put this two lines in your file (on top of it) where you call the function `addFriends`: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` followed by `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. This way you will be able to see the whole error on screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO friends (friends) VALUES ('".$array."') WHERE name = '" . $player . "'";
```

Comment: That should result in the exact same query